# Format money number_format PHP

Tags: php, money-format

I am trying to format from EURO to Latin American countries. But I can't get all of them to format correctly.

These two lines work fine:

```
$currencies['ESP'] = array(2, ',', '.'); // Euro
$currencies['USD'] = array(2, '.', ','); // US Dollar
```

The ones that don't work are these:

1. Mexico I have $ 1,800,520 Mexican Peso and I want to obtain this
   result $ 3,698.00

   ```
   $currencies['MXN'] = array(3, ",", '.'); // México Peso
   ```
2. Colombia $ 2,097,106.36 Colombian peso and I want to get $
   104,637,255.96

   ```
   $currencies['COP'] = array(2, ',', '.'); // Colombiano Peso
   ```
3. Argentina $ 53,609.02 Argentine peso and I want to get $ 10,490

   ```
   $currencies['ARS'] = array(2, ',', '.'); // Argentina Peso
   ```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help.

**Example of my functions:**

```
/**
* @param self::$curr
* @return string
*/
public static function setCurrency($tipo) {
    // Creamos tipo moneda
    $tipoMoneda = ($tipo =='') ? self::$curr : $tipo;

    $moneda = match ($tipoMoneda) {
        'CLF' => "$",
        'COP' => "$",
        'ARS' => "$",
        'USD' => "$",
        'EUR' => "€",
        'MXN' => "$",
    };      
    return $moneda;
}   

/**
* Format price
* @param string
* @param string
*/
public static function toMoney($price,$tipo='') {
    $currencies['EUR'] = array(2, ',', '.'); // Euro
    $currencies['ESP'] = array(2, ',', '.'); // Euro
    $currencies['USD'] = array(2, '.', ','); // US Dollar
    $currencies['COP'] = array(2, ',', '.'); // Colombian Peso
    $currencies['MXN'] = array(3, ",", '.'); // Mexico Peso
    $currencies['CLP'] = array(0,  '', '.'); // Chilean Peso
    $currencies['ARS'] = array(2, ',', '.'); // Argentina Peso

    if ($tipo == '') :
        $money_format = number_format($price, ...$currencies[self::$curr]) . ' ' . self::setCurrency($tipo);
    else:
        $money_format = self::setCurrency($tipo) . number_format($price, ...$currencies[$tipo]);
    endif;
    return $money_format; 
}
```

**EDIT:** The exchange rate i get it from the DB
[image]

```
/**
* Calcular TAXES about original price base
* @param string
* @return string
*/
public static function CalcIva($valor, $arr =[]) {      
            
    // Get default IVA o by (USD-MXN) (COOKIE)
    $getIva = self::$defaultIva;
    
    // Price original
    $price = $valor;
    // Get taxes
    $iva = ($getIva / 100) * $price; 
    // Sum taxes to base price
    $precio = $price + $iva;    

    // On this line if $arr is not null i calculate 1.13 or some else x price
    if ($arr != null) : 
        // Calcul exchange rate (example: 1.13 * 20)
        $precio = $arr['cambio'] * $price;
    endif;
    // Price
    return $precio;     
 }
```

[Example](http://extremera.work/moda-hombre/ropa/sudadera-adicolor-classics-3-bandas/azul/adi222s09i/a2)

To set the cookie i do it on JS

```
/**
 * Select money (header)
 */
let moneda = document.getElementById('slc-moneda');
moneda.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  // Get value option
  let tipo = this.value;
    // Not null
    if (tipo != 0) {
      // Value default, delete cookie
      if (tipo == 'EUR-ES') {
        // Eliminamos cookie, usamos configuracion por defecto
        delCookie('moneda');
        location.reload()
      // Set cookie - new money format
      } else {
        setCookie('moneda', tipo, 365)
        location.reload()     
      } 
    }          
    e.preventDefault()
  })
```

Comment: It sounds like you're not having a problem with the formatting (`number_format`), but you want to do currency conversion. Currency conversion would require an *exchange rate* value, and then some basic multiplication math. None of the code you pasted deals with that.

Comment: @Raxi I have another function that makes this calculation 1.13 x 20 € = x $, I have a select with the countries and their corresponding exchange rate, I update my question

Comment: Yea the added function and sqldata is probably more related to the problem, but i cannot really make out where the problem lies, as this isn't really complete and it being spanish makes it hard for me to follow along. There' s a lot of lines in `CalcIva` that i'd consider strange/dubious but it's hard to say for sure. Overall design-wise i'd say you're mixing a lot of things together (in these class methods), that really shouldn't be in the same place.

Comment: Since it appears you're using an OO-based design, i'd say that the monetary value of a product (or order) should be entirely seperate from the way that value is presented to the user (meaning in his/her desired or chosen currency). Seeing references to *COOKIE* and conversion maths `($getIva / 100) * $price` in the same place is a screaming red flag in that regard.

Comment: @raxi ```$getIVa``` It is the tax of the country, in Spain it is 21%. I save in the DB, the prices in *decimal (5,2)* and when I show the price I calculate the tax in this function ```CalcIva()```, like price + taxes . And in my cookie i put on value USD-EC so i know USD-EC is from ecuador. Later with explode() i separete this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As added background information based on my earlier comments, in case you were having trouble separating all the inter-related concerns, and putting all the pieces together, (i don't know if you are or not); Here is some code i've used in the past solving a similar issue. I've adjusted it based on your datamodel/code and added some comments:

---

Personally, since keeping half the currency information in the database and the other half in code seems messy, i would add 4 columns to your `monedas` database table; namely (in the case of 'Ecuador' for example):

```
`currency_symbol`     => '$'
`decimal_separator`   => '.'
`thousands_separator` => ','
`decimals`            => 2
```

Next you want to decide what datatype you use for price values in PHP.
I'm guessing they are `DECIMAL`s inside your database, in which case you would either use strings (`'65.99'`) or floats (`65.99`) in PHP; generally `string` is prefered as it doesn't suffer from all the oddities that floating point numbers bring to the table.

Alternatively, you could choose to store prices in *cents* in your database, which would allow you to use `INTEGER`s (`6599`) in both the database and in PHP.

Lets assume you use `DECIMAL` in your database, and `string` in PHP; that way you can use the PHP BCMath functions to perform calculations reliably.
Lets also assume that all prices in your database always represent the same currency (eg: your business's local currency, lets assume its `EUR`).

---

Since prices are a complex value in your webshop-style application, you'll want a simple value class to define them.

```
class Price {
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $value = trim((string) $value);
        if (!is_numeric($value) || preg_match('#^(\-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$#D', $value) !== 1) throw Exception('Invalid price value');
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getRawValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    // When printing a price (using echo for example), print it in its converted form (defined later)
    public function __toString() {
        return PriceLocalization::displayLocalPrice( $this );
    }
}
```

---

Next, you want an object that holds (or caches) all the information about all currencies:

```
class Currencies {
    protected static $data = null;

    protected static function pullData() {
        if (is_null(static::$data)) {
            $data = [];
            // Pull the currency/priceconversion info from the DB
            $rows = run_your_dbquery('SELECT * FROM `monera`');
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $row['id_moneda'] = (int) $row['id_moneda'];
                $row['decimals']  = (int) $row['decimals'];
                $data[( $row['id_moneda'] )] = $row;
            }
            // Cache the data incase we have to do more conversions on the current page
            static::$data = $data;
        }
        return static::$data;
    }

    // Returns the entire table of currency/priceconversion info from the DB
    public static function getAll() {
        return static::pullData();
    }

    // Returns one record out of the table of currency/priceconversion info (or exception if invalid)
    public static function getSpecific($id) {
        $data = static::pullData();
        if (array_key_exists($id, $data)) return $data[$id];
        throw new Exception('Bad input');
    }
}
```

---

And another object that deals with the user being able to select a currency sessionwide

```
class UserCurrencySelection {

    // store the users choice in $_COOKIE or $_SESSION or the like (used by your currency-selection selectbox)
    public static function setUserPreference($choice) {
        $_SESSION['currencychoice'] = $choice;
        return true;
    }

    // read the raw value from $_COOKIE or $_SESSION or the like (if any)
    public static function getUserPreference() {
        return ($_SESSION['currencychoice'] ?? null);
    }

    // get either the active currency's record (if any), or otherwise the default record (throw exception if neither exists)
    public static function getActive() {
        try {
            if ($current = static::getUserPreference()) {
                return Currencies::getSpecific( $current );
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {}
        return Currencies::getSpecific( 5 ); // <-- the id of the "default" currency (in this case 5 = EUR)
    }
}
```

---

And finally, the class that actually ties everything together

```
class PriceLocalization {

    // display a specific price adjusted to the -active- currency (with the default currency as fallback)
    public static function displayLocalPrice(Price $price, array $style=[]) {
        $currencyinfo = UserCurrencySelection::getActive();
        return static::displayPriceAs($price, $currencyinfo, $style);
    }

    // display a specific price adjusted to a -specific- currency (eg: id=3 gives colombian price)
    public static function displayPriceInCurrency(Price $price, $id, array $style=[]) {
        $currencyinfo = Currencies::getSpecific( $id );
        return static::displayPriceAs($price, $currencyinfo, $style);
    }

    // perform the actual conversion and formatting
    protected static function displayPriceAs(Price $price, array $currencyinfo, array $style=[]) {
        /* $currencyinfo = [
          'id_monera'           => 4, 
          'moneda'              => 'USD',
          'pais'                => 'Ecuador',
          'ido'                 => 'EC',
          'cambio'              => '1.13',
          'impuesto'            => '12',
          'currency_symbol'     => '$',
          'decimal_separator'   => '.',
          'thousands_separator' => ',',
          'decimals'            => 2,
        ]; */
        // the original price:
        $value_src      = $price->getRawValue();                    
        // Multiply the original price with the conversion rate (`cambio`) to adjust it to this currency (giving us the pre-tax price)
        $value_excl     = bcmul($value_src, $currencyinfo['cambio']);   
        // Calculate the tax, by multiplying the adjusted price with the taxrate (`impuesto`*0.01 to adjust for it being a percentage)
        $tax            = bcmul($value_excl, bcmul('0.01', $currencyinfo['impuesto']));
        // Add the tax to the price to get the "price including tax"
        $value_incl     = bcadd($value_excl, $tax);
        // Decide which of the values you want to display (including or excluding tax)
        $value          = $value_incl;
        // Decide what we want to add before/after the numeric part of the price (the html-encoded version of the currency symbol)
        $label_prefix   = htmlentities( $currencyinfo['currency_symbol'] . ' ');
        $label_suffix   = ''; // or: htmlentities( ' ' . $currencyinfo['moneda']);
        // Change the number into human readable form
        $label          = number_format((float) $value, $currencyinfo['decimals'], $currencyinfo['decimal_separator'], $currencyinfo['thousands_separator']);
        // Convert that into html
        $label          = htmlentities($label);
        // Define some CSS classes to allow for styling
        $classes_prefix = 'p';
        $classes_number = 'v';
        $classes_suffix = 's';
        $classes_full   = 'price';
        // Now assemble all the pieces
        $html_prefix    = sprintf('<span class="%s">%s</span>',     htmlentities($classes_prefix),  $label_prefix);
        $html_number    = sprintf('<span class="%s">%s</span>',     htmlentities($classes_number),  $label);
        $html_suffix    = sprintf('<span class="%s">%s</span>',     htmlentities($classes_suffix),  $label_suffix);
        $html_full      = sprintf('<span class="%s">%s%s%s</span>', htmlentities($classes_full),    $html_prefix,  $html_number,  $html_suffix );
        // Done
        return $html_full;
    }
}
```

---

That's the gist of it.

You can use the `$style` argument that's available on each of the `PriceLocalization` methods to pass arbitrary information along to `displayPriceAs`. Based on that information you could change the way that function assembles its output. For example, you could check if `$style['include_tax']` is set to `true`/`false`, and ifso adjust accordingly:

```
$value = (($style['include_tax'] ?? true) ? $value_incl : $value_excl);
```

---

You could style prices with:

```
.price   { background-color: #EEE; }
.price.p { color: red;   font-weight: bold; }
.price.v { color: green; font-family: courier; }
.price.s { color: blue;  font-weight: bold; }
```

And you could also use the `$style` argument above, to introduce additional classes (in specific cases).

---

It may also be worth setting `bcscale(15);` in your application, to ensure the math is done in a way that cannot result in lost partial pennies.

---

*ps: haven't tested the code after adapting it to your code/datamodel, so it is possible i made a typo somewhere.*

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, your classes look interesting. This week I will try to see if i can adopt it to my code, since the system is an MVC, my +1

Comment: Ah yea; the main point i was trying to make was mostly just to keep some separation of concerns there. Obviously i'm mostly projecting as i've only seen one function (so i could be totally hitting the mark) :)

Comment: Later I will complete all my functions also in the answer, and I will also do a backup and see if I can introduce their classes, again thanks for your time.

Comment: I am doing tests with your class, and I understand the first 3 and I get the results, I have modified the DB, and added those fields. But how can I later print a price in *PriceLocalization*. If i do ```$price = 77.15; echo PriceLozalization::displayLocalPrice(Price $price, array $style=[]);``` i get ```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$price", expecting ")"```

Comment: when reading prices from the database, if the price is in a column called `productprice` then you do $row['productprice'] = new Price($row['productprice']);

Comment: After that you can either just print/echo it, or use PriceLocalization::displayPriceAs($row['productprice'], 4) to get it in currency #4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240434/discussion-between-dbe-and-raxi).

Comment: There is another problem with ```displayPriceAs```, if for example I use euro, **102.85** it shows me **€ 102.00**, it does not include the cents, the same thing happens if I put another currency it is always *,00*, would you know the reason? Another thing, the euro format is **102.85 €**, it is not put forward

Comment: Doing more tests I saw that it does not calculate the tax on the price ```$tax = bcmul($value_excl, bcmul('0.01', $currencyinfo['impuesto']));``` if i change manual to ```$tax = bcmul($value_excl, bcmul('0.01', '10'));``` or 5,etc I always get the same price?

Comment: I'm back in the chat

Comment: How are you friend, can you help me when you have time with this question regarding your answer, I achieved the implementation to the MVC, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508021/mathematical-currency-conversion-failure-php

Comment: Sure thing, i answered there.